# How to check every combination of a pair?

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of points , and I have to find distance between every pair of points. So, creating a function to find the distance is not important here, **but** to to create a loop or function which checks if distance between every pair has been calculated.

Below each item in the list represents an id for corresponding point.

```
   l = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

I want to create a function which checks distance between every pair has been calculated, if not then it calculates the distance with a function say:
      distance_method(a, b)

and stores the value in a data frame as:

```
 point1      point2          distance
 a           b               some_val
 a           c               some_val
```

Note: distance(a,b) = distance(b,a)

Comment: Please add the code how you tried it and what the problem with your code is. On StackOverflow you should not ask other people to write code for you.

Answer (score 3):

you'll be wanting the `itertools` module

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
# get pairs from this list, such that you will get things like
# ('b', 'd') but not the reverse ('d', 'b') 
>>> list(itertools.combinations(lst, 2))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

So I think you'll want to do something like (pseudo-code follows):

```
for pair in itertools.combinations(lst, 2):
    if not in_dataframe(pair):
        add_to_dataframe(pair)
```